# Format datetime to lowercase in GridView's inner Label

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Here is a `GridView` snippet with dates from database:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" ...>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Label ID="dateLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("datevalue", "{0:dd MMM yy, ddd}") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
...
```

Dates look something like `07 Jan 13, Mon`

I want them to look like `07 jan 13, mon`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
The only option available is CSS :)

```
<asp:Label ID="accdateLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("accvaluedate", "{0:dd MMM yy, ddd}") %>' CssClass="grid_date" />

.grid_date
{
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Now it works!

Comment: I feel like there is some way to do that in your markup, but I can't think of it right now.  CSS is probably the simplest solution =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in gridview rowdatabound event:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label dateLbl= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("dateLbl");
        string date=dataLbl.text.tolower();
        dateLBl.text=date;
    }          
}
```